# Cannot Run Sudo After Mac Sierra Upgrade

Tags: mac, macos, sudo

I tried running `sudo` in a terminal and was greeted with the error message:

`sudo: unknown uid 501: who are you?`

I tried doing an `ls -l ~`, and instead of seeing my user name in the file entries, I saw `501`.

I *think* this might have happened in the process of upgrading Mac OS to Sierra; at least I think this is the first time I tried to run `sudo` since upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was fixed by restarting the MacBook Pro.

However, when I first executed the restart, the system hung with a black screen. I then forced the power off (by keeping pressed the power button for several seconds), then turned it on.  Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and wanted to dig it a little more

I figured out it's due to `XPC_FLAGS` variable being set in the session.

Mine was: `XPC_FLAGS=0x2` instead of the current `XPC_FLAGS=0x0`

New session (new tab) did solve the issue for me but no idea what did set it in a first place :| ? It seems to be xcode related when I google around and that could also explain the sneaky change in the background.

Hopefully someone will add another step to that story here :)

Comment: I've had the same issue and don't have (and never have had) xcode installed. However, I do have the xcode command line utils installed (needed for `git` and more).